# Split very large files on record border

Tags: bash

I have to split a very large file into N smaller files with the following constraints:

1. I have to split on record border
2. Record separator can be any character
3. the number of records in the resulting N files should be the same (+/- 1 record)
4. I can just use bash and standard coreutils (I have a working solution in Perl but we're not allowed to install Perl/Python/etc)
5. This is not a real constraint but - if possible - I'd like to scan the original (large) file just once.

Sort order of the resulting files is not important.

My working solution in Perl reads the original file and writes...

```
- the 1st record to the first file
- ...
- the Nth record to the Nth file
- the N+1 record back to the first file
- etc
```

So - at the end - with a single scan of the initial file I do get several smaller files with the same number of records (+/- 1).

For example, assume this is the input file:

```
1,1,1,1A2,2,2,2A3,
3,3,3A4,4,4,4A5,5,
5,5A6,6,6,6A7,7,7,
7,A8,8,8,8A9,9,9,9
A0,0,0,0
```

With record separator = 'A' and N = 3 I should get three files:

```
# First file:
1,1,1,1A2,2,2,2A3,
3,3,3

# Second file
4,4,4,4A5,5,
5,5A6,6,6,6

# Third file:
7,7,7,
7,A8,8,8,8A9,9,9,9
A0,0,0,0
```

**UPDATE**

Here you have the perl code. I tried to make it as simple and readable as I can:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use locale;
use Getopt::Std;

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Declaring variables
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
my %op = ();        # Command line parameters hash
my $line = 0;       # Output file line number
my $fnum = 0;       # Output file number
my @fout = ();      # Output file names array
my @fhnd = ();      # Output file handles array
my @ifiles = ();    # Input file names
my $i = 0;          # Loop variable

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Handling command line arguments
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
getopts("o:n:hvr:", \%op);
die "Usage: lfsplit [-h] -n number_of_files",
    " [-o outfile_prefix] [-r rec_sep_decimal] [-v] input_file(s)\n"
    if $op{h} ;
if ( @ARGV ) {
    @ifiles = @ARGV ;
} else {
    die "No input files...\n" ;
}
$/ = chr($op{r}) if $op{r} ;

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setting Default values
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$op{o} |= 'out_' ;

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Body - split in round-robin to $op{n} files
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $op{n} ; $i++ ) {
    local *OUT ;                # Localize file glob
    $fout[$i] = sprintf "%s_%04d.out", $op{o}, $i ;
    open ( OUT, "> $fout[$i]" ) or
        die "[lfsplit] Error writing to $fout[$i]: $!\n";
    push ( @fhnd , *OUT ) ;
}
$i = 0 ;
foreach ( @ifiles ) {
    print "Now reading $_ ..." if $op{v} ;
    open ( IN, "< $_" ) or
        die "[lfsplit] Error reading $op{i}: $!\n" ;
    while ( <IN> ) {
        print { $fhnd[$i] } $_ ;
        $i = 0 if ++$i >= $op{n} ;
    }
    close IN ;
}
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $op{n} ; $i++ ) {
    close $fhnd[$i] ;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Exit
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
exit 0 ;
```

Comment: No free coding here on S.O., right? Please include your `perl` code and maybe someone can give you some pointers on converting to `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Yes, You perfectly understood the situation.... Perl code in the UPDATE section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for kicks, a pure bash solution, no external programs and no forking (I think):

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
separator=$2
outputs=$3

i=0
while read -r -d"$separator" record; do
  out=$((i % outputs)).txt
  if ((i < outputs)); then
    : > $out
  else
    echo -n "$separator" >> $out
  fi
  echo -n "$record" >> $out
  ((i++))
done < $input
```

Sadly this will reopen every file for every output operation. I'm sure it's possible to fix this, using `<>` to open a file descriptor and keep it open, but using that with non-literal file descriptors is a bit of a pain.